# Disable and enable dropdown options using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have 2 drop-down like below:

```
<div class="col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper">
  <select class="form-control switcher" id ="1st-dd">
   <option value="23" disable_child= "y" class="disableDropdown">No Pocket</option>
   <option value="24" disable_child= "n" selected="selected"
 class="disableDropdown">1 Pocket</option>
   <option value="25" disable_child= "n" class="disableDropdown">2 Pocket</option>
 </select>  
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper">
  <select class="form-control switcher" id = "flap-drop">
    <option value="26">No Flap</option>
    <option value="27" selected="selected">Flap Pocket</option> 
 </select> 
</div>
```

What I want is when I select `No Pocket` in dropdown1, disable both the options of dropdown 2. And enable If any other option is selected in dropdown 1.

Here's what I am trying.

```
$(".disableDropdown").click(function(){
 //alert($(this).attr("disable_child"));
  if( $(this).attr("disable_child") == "y") 
  {
   $("#flap-drop").attr("disabled",true);
  }
 else{
   $("#flap-drop").attr("disabled",false);
  } 
 });
```

What's wrong here?

[Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/gfp4kbvg/) the fiddle for the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$("#1st-dd").change(function() {
    $("#flap-drop").attr("disabled", this.value=="23"); 
    // or $("#flap-drop").toggle(this.value!="23");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper">
  <select class="form-control switcher" id="1st-dd">
    <option value="23" disable_child="y" class="disableDropdown">No Pocket</option>
    <option value="24" disable_child="n" selected="selected" class="disableDropdown">1 Pocket</option>
    <option value="25" disable_child="n" class="disableDropdown">2 Pocket</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper">
  <select class="form-control switcher" id="flap-drop">
    <option value="26">No Flap</option>
    <option value="27" selected="selected">Flap Pocket</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Try it this way.
Instead of click i used `change` and compare the values same as you did

Comment: when I select No pocket in dropdown 1, both the options are getting disabled all right, but even then the dropdown looks like we can still do some select. So Is there anyway that the whole select option gets disabled?

Comment: yes remove the children from the selector when i read you question that is how i understand what you wanted i will update

Comment: Please drop the if and the option:selected and do `"disabled",this.value=="23")`

Comment: @mplungjan i can be a completely different answer my approach is to use the OP previous code and did some modification. pls feel free to update the answer if you think it needs some revision.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `prop()`:

```
$('option').prop('disabled', 'disabled')
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#1st-dd").change(function() {
    $("#flap-drop").attr("disabled", this.value=="23"); 
    // or $("#flap-drop").toggle(this.value!="23");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper">
  <select class="form-control switcher" id="1st-dd">
    <option value="23" disable_child="y" class="disableDropdown">No Pocket</option>
    <option value="24" disable_child="n" selected="selected" class="disableDropdown">1 Pocket</option>
    <option value="25" disable_child="n" class="disableDropdown">2 Pocket</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2 uno_part_wrapper">
  <select class="form-control switcher" id="flap-drop">
    <option value="26">No Flap</option>
    <option value="27" selected="selected">Flap Pocket</option>
  </select>
</div>
```