# Disable Drop-down using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two dropdowns options then Disable First Drop-down Menu Options when second Drop-down options is selected or viceversa

```js
function coatedpaper() {
    var option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    $('#showoption').val(option);
    $('#plastic').prop("disabled", true);
}

function plasticpaper() {
    $('#paper').prop("disabled", true);
}

function chgSelect(which) 
    {
        // alert(which);
    if (which == 'coatedpaper') {
        if (document.getElementById('paper').selectedIndex == 0) //Unlock plastic
            document.getElementById('plastic').disabled = false;
        else // lock plastic
            document.getElementById('plastic').disabled = true;
    } else {
        if (document.getElementById('plastic').selectedIndex == 0) //Unlock paper
            document.getElementById('paper').disabled = false;
        else // lock paper
            document.getElementById('paper').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<legend>
  <h1>Fill Quote Form</h1>
</legend>
<div class="quote-form">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6">Plastic Coated Paper :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control" name="plastic_coated_paper" id="plastic_coated_paper" onchange="chgSelect('coatedpaper');">
          <option selected value="0" id="selectpaper">Select Paper</option>
          <option>Black Centered 330</option>
          <option>Black Centered 320</option>
          <option>Black Centered 315</option>
          <option>Black Centered 305</option>
          <option>Black Centered 300</option>
          <option>Black Centered 280</option>
          <option>White Centered 330</option>
          <option>White Centered 320</option>
          <option>White Centered 315</option>
          <option>White Centered 305</option>
          <option>White Centered 300</option>
          <option>White Centered 280</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3" style="text-align:center;">OR</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-6">100% Pure Plastic :</label>
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <select class="form-control" name="pure_plastic" id="pure_plastic" onchange="chgSelect('plasticpaper');">
          <option selected value="0">Select Plastic</option>
          <option>250 Microns</option>
          <option>260 Microns</option>
          <option>270 Microns</option>
          <option>280 Microns</option>
          <option>290 Microns</option>
          <option>300 Microns</option>
          <option>310 Microns</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3">(Minimum Quantity 1000 Decks)</div>
```

I have two dropdowns options. Both dropdown's value and options are different. The question is that Disable First  Drop-down Menu Options when second Drop-down options is selected or Disable second   Drop-down Menu Options when first Drop-down options is selected ....

Plastic coated have 12 option and 100% pure plastic have 7 option, if out of 12 option i select one option then of 100% pure plastic  all options should be disabled or if i select one option of 100% pure plastic option then all 12 option of plastic coated paper should be disabled

Plastic coated paper  and 100% pure plastic are two dropdown option here

[image: example of dropdown option]

Comment: Post your relevant html.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable and enable dropdown options using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35146242/disable-and-enable-dropdown-options-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Try this example

**Html**

```
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>  
<select class="ddl">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>
```

**Script**

```
    $('.ddl').change(function(){
       if($(this).val()!="0") {   
           $('select[class="ddl"]').not($(this)).find('option').attr('disabled','disabled');
       }
    })
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f80zdjnf/)

Answer (score 0):

You can make select disable using prop in jquery.

`$('#selectID').prop('disabled', 'disabled');`

Hope you will get some idea on that.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this meet your requirment....please find this solution:- https://jsfiddle.net/f80zdjnf/11/

```
<select class="ddl1">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>  
<select class="ddl2">
<option value="0"> Select </option>
<option value="1"> One </option>
<option value="2"> Two </option>
<option value="3"> Three </option>
<option value="4"> Four </option>
<option value="5"> Five </option>
<option value="6"> Six </option>
</select>
```

and js part is like below

```
$('.ddl1').change(function(){
   if($(this).val()!="0") {   $('select[class="ddl2"]').find('option').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else
{
$('select[class="ddl2"]').find('option').removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
$('.ddl2').change(function(){
   if($(this).val()!="0") {   $('select[class="ddl1"]').find('option').attr('disabled','disabled');
}
else
{
$('select[class="ddl1"]').find('option').removeAttr("disabled");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may disable the other select box uisng jQuery .Include Jquery js file in your page and add following script to the page .

```
<script>
            $(document).on("change", "#plastic_coated_paper",
            function(event){
                $("#pure_plastic").prop("disabled",true);
            }
            );
            $(document).on("change", "#pure_plastic",
            function(event){
                $("#plastic_coated_paper").prop("disabled",true);
            }
            );
        </script>
```

Comment: You may include the jquery  using   <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>